# BOOTSTRAP: insert accordion after ajax request

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I need to insert an accordion thanks to bootstrap to organize my data. The fact is, I create all the elements with dom to create my tree after the first load of the page with an ajax request. 
But bootstrap doesn't take account of it because it has been created after the page first initialization.

The aim is to have several lines of results and if you click on one line ,it expands and gives more details.

How  can I dynamically create this accordion?

Answer (score 1):

By generating the HTML and inserting it into the page where you want it.

After you have added it to the page, then invoke:

```
$(".collapse").collapse()
```

All of Bootstrap's Javascript modules support manual creation.